Problem with building webshop it looks good but when i view in other browsers it doesnt appear like i made
can anyone help me with this issue, i have woodmart and elementor webshop on wordpress. I made the webshop look good but when i put it live it doesnt appear like i made only in chrome in looks good or if i am logged in in admin account.
This is a staging site so i am developing this and wanted to look if it shows good but it doesnt anyone easy fix?
this is website in admin mode:
and this is in another browser:

As a third party plugin, Elementor is off topic for this Stack. Support requests would be better directed to their own forum.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
